# How to handle events in data grid's column template with reference to the cell's content?

Tags: c#, silverlight, datagrid, telerik

I am using Telerik but I guess my problem would also arise with a regular DataGrid. The code below shows a DataTemplate for a GridViewDataColumn which is part of my MainPage.xaml.

```
<telerik:RadTreeListView x:Name ="MyGrid" ...>
    <telerik:RadTreeListView.Columns>
        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel ...>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" MouseLeftButtonDown="OnMouseLeftButtonDown"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
        </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
    </telerik:RadTreeListView.Columns>
</telerik:RadTreeListView>
```

In the code behind I set

```
MyGrid.ItemsSource = items; // items is an ObservableCollection<MyItem>
```

and MyItem is my view model for each column cell. There I define all the different properties such as Name I bind to. This part works very well. What does not work at all is the call of the method OnMouseLeftButtonDown which is part of the MyItem class. The compiler complains that she can not find it.

Answer (score 0):

Code-behind event handlers don't work from inside DataTemplates (not sure why exactly, but I guess something to do with compile-time vs runtime resolution of the XAML elements).

There are several alternatives -- one is to use a "FindAncestor" binding to refer to the control root, along with a Blend SDK "EventTrigger" / "CallMethodAction".  So if your XAML looks like this:

```
<UserControl x:Name="userControl">
    ...
    <telerik:RadTreeListView ...>
```

Then you could attach a mouse-click handler like this:

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel ...>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                        <ei:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=telerik:RadTreeListView},Path=DataContext}"
                                             MethodName="OnMouseLeftButtonDown" />
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </TextBlock> 
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
```

An alternative to using the Blend SDK would be to use a `Button`, or another control that supports `Command`, instead of the `TextBlock`.  That way, you can just bind the Button's command to a property in your view-model with:

```
Command={Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=telerik:RadTreeListView},Path=DataContext.SomeCommand}
```

Notice that you don't have to worry about the mouse-click event in this case, since `Button` wires the handler up for you internally, and invokes your command when it is clicked.